# JPA 2.0 multiple OR in where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Couldn't find an answer for this one. We have a criteria query that should output SQL something along these lines:

```
select * from x where x.one is null and 
( 
 (x.two = 2 and x.three = 3) or
 (x.two = 3 and x.three = 4) or
 (x.two = 5 and x.three = 6) or 
 etc
 etc
)
```

We're using Hibernate 3.6.5. First we collect the adds to a list and then we proceed to add those to disjunction like this:

```
List<Predicate> ands = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
ands.add(cb.and(cb.equal(attrExpr, 2), cb.equal(attrExpr, 2)));
ands.add(cb.and(cb.equal(attrExpr, 3), cb.equal(attrExpr, 3)));

predicates.add(cb.or(ands.toArray(new Predicate[ands.size()])));
```

Where cb is the CriteriaBuilder and attrExpr is the path to x.two. The generated SQL is as follows:

```
from
    ccp_organization organizati0_ 
left outer join
    ccp_orgattribute_org attributes1_ 
        on organizati0_.id=attributes1_.organization_id 
where
    (
        organizati0_.deleted_=? 
        or organizati0_.deleted_ is null
    ) 
    and (
        attributes1_.id=2 
        and attributes1_.id=2 
        or attributes1_.id=3 
        and attributes1_.id=3 
        or attributes1_.id=4 
        and attributes1_.id=4
    )
```

And it should be:

```
from
    ccp_organization organizati0_ 
left outer join
    ccp_orgattribute_org attributes1_ 
        on organizati0_.id=attributes1_.organization_id 
where
    (
        organizati0_.deleted_=? 
        or organizati0_.deleted_ is null
    ) 
    and (
        (attributes1_.id=2 
        and attributes1_.id=2)
        or 
        (attributes1_.id=3 
        and attributes1_.id=3)
        or 
        (attributes1_.id=4 
        and attributes1_.id=4)
    )
```

Comment: Haha, asked without thinking this through.. The SQL operator precedence takes care of this. Doh.